# What is smtp_server.ehlo and what is it used for?

Tags: python

I was seeing a smtplib python tutorial, and I see these code lines:

`smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)`

`smtp_server.ehlo()`

What is that .ehlo used for?

Comment: smtplib is poorly abstracted, requiring you to know about `ehlo` email protocol details. It should just do this automatically when you connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EHLO` ("Extended Hello") is the SMTP command the client uses to tell the server that it is an SMTP client (`HELO` is the old SMTP protocol, while `EHLO` is the extended SMTP initialisation command).

`EHLO` was [introduced with RFC 1869](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1869#section-4) back in 1995, so for any actual use you'll se `EHLO` used these days.

In effect it's just telling your smtp library to send the "Hello, I'm an STMP client and want to use the extended command set" message.

Comment: The other use of ehlo is to find out what the server supports (e.g., 8bit mime or authentication)